# Laravel:can i add some string after an uri without changing its parsing result?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to implement static file cache to bypass php processing.

say we have an uri '/api/lecturers/page/1'.What I want is that clients can send requests to '/api/lecturers/page/1.iphone6.json'.And if there is a static json file,they can get the result directly.if not,requests are routed to '/api/lecturers/page/1',retrieving data and writing it to the json file.

However,if you request '/api/lecturers/page/1.iphone6.json',the last segment is parsed as '1.iphone6.json',which is in fact a wrong argument to the api, rather than '1'.

so the question is how to make laravel neglect '.iphone6.json' part of the uri?Or do you have any ideas to make the same effect?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:I tried to configure nginx as @ateoa said

```
if (-f $request_filename){
    break;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "(.*?)\.(.*?)\.json"){
    rewrite ^(.*?)\.(.*?)\.json$    $1;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

When I request

```
'http://xxx/api/v1/lecture/list/date/1/desc.iphone6.json'
```

,it results in nginx error ""/wwwpath/api/v1/lecture/list/date/1/desc" failed (2: No such file or directory)"

Now, I have no idea how to go on T_T!

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle your request with RESTFUL API which produces a cleaner URL.

This `'/api/lecturers/page/1.iphone6.json'` is a little bit messy

Why not use `/api/v1/lecturers/page/iphone6` -- Its a good practice to include version name in your API

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::resource('lecturers/page', 'LecturersController');
});
```

Then in your controller

```
class LecturersController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($iphone)
    { ///api/lecturers/page/iphone

        $json_file = "{$iphone}.json";
        $json_file_path = app_path("public/json/$json_file");
        $json_data = '';

        //Let me assume your static json files are stored in public/json

        if( !File::exists($json_file_path) ) {

            $page = Page::where('iphone', $iphone)->get();

            //Avoid creating a file for invalid phones
            if($page->count()){

                $json_data = json_encode($page->toArray());

                fopen($json_file_path, "w");

                file_put_contents($json_file_path,$json_data);
            }
        }elseif(File::exists($json_file_path)){
            $json_data = file_get_contents($json_file_path);
        }

        //There is Response::json() in Laravel 4 however this will do

        return Response::make($json_data, 200);

    }

}
```

//This might not be the best implementation of what you want but i believe you can improve it

Comment: thank your for your advice for api version thing.i'll take it.

Comment: I want to bypass php so that nginx can serve much much more requests per second.If I have to process the logic in php,it's meaningless to do these dirty works.

Answer (score 0):

`/api/lecturers/page/1?jsonfilename=iphone6.json
    /api/lecturers/page/1
    $_GET['jsonfilename']`

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but '/api/lecturers/page/1?jsonfilename=iphone6.json' doesn't directly access the static json file.I have to do some work in php,which is not what I want.

Comment: Oh~ You make the logic in ngnix.

Comment: In nginx, it has `if` and `try_files`, you can add the logic in nginx and `rewrite` the url to the static json file, or to the api route.